# Tomcat/Ubuntu not using correct JDK

Tags: java, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, tomcat6

I am trying to use an AMI created from ubuntu instance running on AWS. The original instance had the java 1.7.0_21 installed and JAVA_HOME pointing to it. I compile my classes with compatibility set to 1.7 as I need the javax.net.ssl package. My application runs fine inside tomcat. But when I try to run an instance created from AMI, I am getting the `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class` 
error.  I do a `ps` on the processes running and I see the tomcat has been started with jdk 1.7.0_21 as expected. I am not sure why I get this error.

```
  ubuntu@XXXX:~$ ps aux | grep tomcat
    tomcat6   2554  0.8 35.3 997460 213768 ?       Sl   07:01   0:21 /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat6/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat6-tomcat6-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Comment: What is the class name after the exception - Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class

Comment: why do you need the class name? it is not from any library. It is our own app class.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError happens because of a higher JDK during compile time and lower JDK during runtime. Could you please check, with which version your code is compiled?

The version number shown describes the version of the JRE the class file is compatible with.

The reported major numbers are:

```
J2SE 8 = 52,
J2SE 7 = 51,
J2SE 6.0 = 50,
J2SE 5.0 = 49,
JDK 1.4 = 48,
JDK 1.3 = 47,
JDK 1.2 = 46,
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

(source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file )

Comment: Like I have mentioned in the question I have compiled setting the source/target compatibility to 1.7 which means that it should run on J2SE 1.7. I am trying to get the tomcat started with JDK 1.7 and I expect it  not to have any problems supporting 51